# Structured Streaming with mapGroupState causing GC and Performance Issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, garbage-collection, spark-structured-streaming

In our application we are using structured streaming  with MapGroupWithState in combination with read from Kafka.

After starting the application, during the initial batches the performance is good, if i see the kafka lastProgress almost 65K per second. After few batches the performance is reduced completely to around 2000 per second.

in MapGroupWithState Function basically an update and comparison to the value from state store is happening(code snippet provided below).

Number of Offsets from Kafka - 100000

After starting the application, during the initial batches the performance is good, if i see the kafka lastProgress almost 65K per second. After few batches the performance is reduced completely to around 2000 per second.

If we see the Thread Dump from one of executor then there is no suspicious except Blocked threads from spark UI

[image: Thread Count]

[image: Thread Block]

GC Stats from one of the executor as below , seems

Didn't see much difference after GC

[image: Before GC]

[image: After GC]

**Code Snippet**

```
case class MonitoringEvent(InternalID: String, monStartTimestamp: Timestamp, EndTimestamp: Timestamp, Stream: String, ParentID: Option[String])


val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Config.uatKafkaUrl)
      .option("subscribe", Config.interBranchInputTopic)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100000")
      .option("request.required.acks", "all")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")    


        val me: Dataset[MonitoringEvent] = df.select(from_json($"value", schema).as("data")).select($"data.*").as[MonitoringEvent]

        val IB =   me.groupByKey(x => (x.ParentID.getOrElse(x.InternalID)))
        .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout)(IBTransformer.mappingFunctionIB _)
        .flatMap(x => x)


    val IBStream = IB
      .select(to_json(struct($"*")).as("value"), $"InternalID".as("key"))
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .queryName("InterBranch_Events_KafkaWriter")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Config.uatKafkaUrl)
      .option("topic", Config.interBranchTopicComplete)
      .option("checkpointLocation", Config.interBranchCheckPointDir)
      .outputMode("update")
      .start()



object IBTransformer extends Serializable {

  case class IBStateStore(InternalID: String, monStartTimestamp: Timestamp)

  def mappingFunctionIB(intrKey: String, intrValue: Iterator[MonitoringEvent], intrState: GroupState[IBStateStore]): Seq[MonitoringEvent] = {

    try {
      if (intrState.hasTimedOut) {
            intrState.remove()
               Seq.empty
      } else {

        val events = intrValue.toSeq
        if (events.map(_.Status).contains(Started)) {

           val tmp = events.filter(x => (x.Status == Started && x.InternalID == intrKey)).head
           val toStore = IBStateStore(tmp.InternalID, tmp.monStartTimestamp)
            intrState.update(toStore)
            intrState.setTimeoutDuration(1200000) 
        }
        val IB = events.filter(_.ParentID.isDefined)
        if (intrState.exists && IB.nonEmpty) {
          val startEvent = intrState.get
          val IBUpdate = IB.map {x => x.copy(InternalID = startEvent.InternalID, monStartTimestamp = startEvent.monStartTimestamp) }
          IBUpdate.foreach(id => intrState.update((IBStateStore(id.InternalID, id.monStartTimestamp)))) // updates the state with new IDs
          IBUpdate
        } else {
          Seq.empty
        }
      }
    }

    catch
    .
    .
    .       
  }
}
```

Number of executers used - 8
Exector Memory - 8G
Driver Memory - 8G

Java options and memory i provide in my spark Submit script

```
 --executor-memory 8G \
 --executor-cores 8 \
 --num-executors 4 \
 --driver-memory 8G \
--driver-java-options "-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dconfig.file=configIB.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=IBprocessor.log4j.properties" \
```

Tried using G1GC in java options, but there is no improvement. The keys we hold is also less than the size provided, so not sure where it is going wrong .

Any suggestions to improve performance and eliminate GC Issues ?

Comment: Please take a heapdump and see whether you're hitting SPARK-23682 or not. If you hit the same, Spark 2.4.0 will remedy the issue.